# Qual "collate" UTF-8 é o mais apropriada para Web (multi-linguagem)

Tags: mysql, aplicação-web

Geralmente costumo usar `utf8_general_ci` por padrão em meus projetos, porém recentemente me deparei que outros desenvolvedores costumam usar `utf8_unicode_ci`

- `utf8_general_ci`: Unicode (multi-linguagem), Não diferencia maiúsculas/minúsculas
- `utf8_unicode_ci`: Unicode (multi-linguagem), Não diferencia maiúsculas/minúsculas

Qual destas seria a mais apropriada para Web ou existe algum *outro utf-8* mais apropriado para web?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A principal diferença está em como o `utf8_general_ci` e `utf8_unicode_ci` fazem as comparações parecidas com alguns fonemas.

Por exemplo, na língua alemã o caractere “ß” seria equivalente ao "ss". Como o `utf8_unicode_ci` tem que fazer esse tipo de comparação combinando mais de um caractere, ele **é mais lento** que `utf8_general_ci`.

Ou seja, caso sua aplicação não precisa de comparações entre caracteres em múltiplos idiomas, vá de `utf8_general_ci`.

Porém considerando sistemas que funcionam de forma global e devem trabalhar com multiplos idiomas, como um Wordpress ou Wikimedia por exemplo, usar `utf8_unicode_ci` é uma boa saída.

Outro chartset interessante de se mencionar é o `utf8_bin`. Ele tem como base a comparação bit a bit dos caracteres, resultando então numa comparação **case-sensitive**, ao contrário dos outros collations.

**Conclusão**

A escolha do collation depende muito da natureza de nossa aplicação. Além do `uft8`, existem outros charsets para atender necessidades de uma região específica (`latin1` por exemplo) e como cada escopo varia muito, não creio que seja possível apontar o mais apropriado para todos os casos.

Na maioria dos casos, o `utf8_general_ci` irá atender, pois, como o próprio nome sugere, é para uso geral e mais comum de ser encontrado. Todavia, é interessante conhecer que existem outros collations que podem atender uma necessidade mais específica, como o `utf8_unicode_ci` e `utf8_bin`.

Fonte: [Documentação do MySQL<sup>en</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)