# Como determinar a ordenação de caracteres acentuados no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, acentuação, collation

Minha tabela usa "utf8-general-ci" então todos os acentos são OK.
Mas quando eu tenho por exemplo Aa, Ac e Áb e que eu quero filtrar "por ordem alfabético", o resultado é:

- Aa
- Ac
- Áb

Sobre Excel, o resultado é:

- Aa
- Áb
- Ac

o que é mais lógico.

Como fazer para ter o mesmo resultado usando MySQL? Eu tentei mudar a collation para latin_general_ci ou outros, mas muda nada...

Comment: Acho que esse <a href="http://imasters.com.br/artigo/1203/postgresql/ordenacao-de-caracteres-acentuados/">Link</a> atende as suas necessidades

Answer (score 4):

Aparentemente o problema ocorre especificamente com o `latin1_general_ci` (conforme este [link](http://ajuda.maxrevenda.com.br/resolvendo-problemas-de-caracteres-acentuados-no-mysql/)):

- `latin1_general_ci`: Não há distinção entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Buscando por `teste`, registros como `Teste` ou `TESTE` serão retornados.
- `latin1_swedish_ci`: Não distingue letras minúsculas e maiúsculas e nem caracteres acentuados e com cedilha, ou seja, o registro que contém a palavra `Intuição` será retornado quando houver uma procura pela palavra `intúicao`.

E é por causa da distinção que ocorre esse ordenamento diferente.

Um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `products` (`name`) VALUES ('Aa'), ('Ac'), ('Áb');
```

Se eu usar a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER by name ASC;
```

Irá retornar isto:

```
+----+------+
| ID | NAME |
+----+------+
| 1  | Aa   |
| 2  | Ac   |
| 3  | Áb   |
+----+------+
```

Online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7131/1

Se eu usar com `utf8_general_ci` (ou `utf8_unicode_ci`):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Irá retornar isto:

```
+----+------+
| ID | NAME |
+----+------+
| 1  | Aa   |
| 3  | Áb   |
| 2  | Ac   |
+----+------+
```

> **Nota:** Com `utf8_unicode_ci`, `utf8_general_ci` e `latin1_swedish_ci` tive os resultados esperados, apenas o `latin1_general_ci` apresentou tal comportamento.

Outro problema que pode ocorrer é com mudanças do `COLLATE` no momento de *exportar* e *importar* (em uma possível restauração de backup) os dados foram convertidos para outro formato (acontece muito isto por causa de softwares como *PhpMyAdmin*).

### Como fazer backups sem ocorrer problemas com a codificação

Existem vários métodos de fazer backup, mas ao meu ver o mais prático (se for um servidor online principalmente) é usar `SSH` com `mysqldump`

- [How to backup a single table in a MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6682916/1518921)

No terminal (no servidor via SSH) você deve usar o seguinte comando para exportar uma tabela:

```
mysqldump banco_de_dados tabela > <caminho completo>/table_name.sql
```

Nota: Se quiser baixar via FTP no lugar de `table_name.sql` digite um caminho acessível pelo `FTP` para poder fazer o download posteriormente (é bem útil para uma rotina de backups)

Importar uma tabela:

```
mysql -u <usuario> -p banco_de_dados
mysql> tabela <caminho completo>/table_name.sql
```

### Possíveis soluções

**Não** recomendo ficar tentando setar o `COLLATE` na query, pois isto seria mais uma "gambiarra" e provavelmente se você esquecer de adicionar a alguma query podem ocorrer diferenças nos resultados.

Recomendo recriei as tabelas usando um `COLLATE` que de suporte para considerar caracteres com acentos iguais aos sem acentos, você pode usar o `latin1_swedish_ci` ou `utf8*`

Leia isto acaso venha usar o utf8:

- [Qual "collate" UTF-8 é o mais apropriada para Web (multi-linguagem)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43281/3635)
- [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193/3635)

> **Nota:** Conforme a resposta a pergunta [ [Qual "collate" UTF-8 é o mais apropriada para Web (multi-linguagem)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43281/3635) ] o `utf8_general_ci` considera acentos "iguais" as letras sem acentos, mas nem todos caracteres são considerados iguais, como por exemplo o `ß` só terá o mesmo resultado que `ss` se usar `utf8_unicode_ci` (leia na mesma resposta sobre vantagens e desvantagens), o que é um "problema" semelhante ao do `latin1_general_ci`

Answer (score 4):

Bom, vou fazer uma pergunta porque a partir da resposta do Guilherme Nascimento eu achei a resposta.
O problema não e um problema de COLLATE mas um problema entre Mysql et PHP. Sabemos que PHP não usa utf8. Foi previsto para PHP6 mas vai 'teoricamente" acontecer somente em PHP7.
Vamos então ver como fazer um site em utf8 para entender a dificuldade.
No inicio, vou criar minha BDD e depois as tabelas. Tudo em utf8. Quando vou testar, usando o teste de Guilherme Nascimento, ta tudo certo. Legal!

Depois vou criar meu codigo PHP e criar a pagina HTML onde vou colocar:

```
   <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
```

Depois vou criara um documento php, onde vou colocar por exemplo:

```
   define ("TITULO","Direção");
```

vou salvar em UTF8 e enviar usando um software FTP, que não vai mudar o código.

Vou criar uma pagina com um formulário e um campo INPUT usando o titulo definido no meu define.
Legal! Vou ver "Direção" como titulo, vou digitar por exemplo "direção nacional" no campo. No submit, o conteúdo vai ser enviado na segunda pagina PHP e eu vou salvar usando um SELECT.
Na leitura, vou simplesmente fazer um SELECT * FROM TAB. Vou fazer um echo colocando  titulo e depois o contendo da minha tabela e vou ter:

```
    Direção: direção nacional
```

Neste momento, eu vou ter certeza que tudo esta certo. Mas não é. De verdade, dentro da tabela, eu não tenho "direção nacional". Eu tenho "dire��o nacional". Mas como na leitura, tem conversão automática dos dados, isso ma da a ilusão que os dados são corretas. O problema e que, quando eu vou precisar fazer um ORDER BY, MySQL vai fazer usando "dire��o nacional" e o resultado vai ser errado.

No seu exemplo Guilherme Nascimento usa um fiddle então, um sistema fechada. O que explica que funciona perfeitamente.

**Soluçao**

A solução e simples. Imediatamente depois do mysqli_connect, precisa colocar mysqli_set_charset.

```
   $handle = mysqli_connect($sql_host,$sql_user,$sql_password,$sql_database);
   mysqli_set_charset($handle,'utf8');
```

A partir disso, quando vc vai digitar "direção", na tabela vai ter "direção" e o ORDER BY vai ser coreto.

**Mas, para os dados antigos???**

Infelizmente, exportar para re-importar vai mudar nada. Porque eu vou exportar "dire��o nacional" e reimportar "dire��o nacional". De verdade, precisa ler os dados SEM fazer o mysqli_set_charset, depois fazer o mysqli_set_charset e fazer um INSERT.

Então:

```
    1 - Conectar usando mysqli_connect (sem fazer o mysqli_set_charset)
    2 - Ler os dados da tabela e salvar para preparar o query para INSERT elas
    3 - Fazer um TRUNCATE na tabela
    4 - Fazer o mysqli_set_charset($handle,'utf8');
    5 - Fazer o INSERT dos dados
```

Assim, vou ler da forma "antiga" e depois, vou "insert" da nova forma.

Agora, tudo esta certo!!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pra mim o ponto-chave desta resposta é que é necessário definir o charset da conexão entre o PHP e o banco (com `set_charset` ou um `SET names ...`). Justamente porque o PHP não usa UTF8. Se você define `$foo = 'acentuação'`, a representação que o PHP faz da string não está em UTF8. Por isso mesmo existem as funções de encode/decode na linguagem.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu li novamente a pergunta com mais atenção, realmenet a própria resposta do usuário responde ao problema e após o seu comentário entendi, PHP com UTF-8 se refere a API do MySql e não ao PHP necessariamente. Obrigado! +1 Resposta, +1 para o seu comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode sobrescrever o *collation* padrão por outro através da cláusula `COLLATE`.
Por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY campo COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Além disso, observe se o campo também está com o mesmo `collation` da tabela.

Comment: A tabela já esta em utf8_general_ci então o COLLATE faz nada e mesmo com um "segundo" COLLATE, o resultado e o mesmo.

Comment: Pois é. Pensei que por alguma razão desconhecida o collation da tabela estivesse sendo ignorado.

Comment: Qual a engine da sua tabela?

Comment: Mais uma coisa, tente mudar o collation do campo também.