# Consulta no mysql com php não retorna resultado em consultas com acentos

Tags: php, mysql

Olá tenho um sistema em php/mysql usando zend 1.12, porem ao consultar o banco mysql com uma palavra que nao tenha acento e na tabela tem acento, nao retorna nenhum resultado por exemplo:

ao pesquisar: {joao} e no banco esta {joão}, nao retorna resultados.

o banco de dados esta configurado com:  InnoDB  latin1_general_ci.

quero saber se tem como eu retirar os acentos dos registros que ja estao na tabela para a consulta ocorrer naturalmente quando o usuario fizer a pesquisa de palavras sem acento.

ex: usuario digita: {atencao}
na tabela tenho a frase: {Muito cuidado tenha atenção ao retornar da viajem.}

isso retorna 0 result.

Não sei se consegui ser claro, ja procurei aqui no forum e nao achei nada parecido.

se alguem poder indicar um link ou dar alguma dica ou ate mesmo esclarecer este.

Obrigado.

Comment: Veja se isto lhe ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51317/3635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes realizar a consulta sem que a mesma considere a acentuação da seguinte forma:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM minhaTabela
WHERE minhaColuna LIKE '%joao%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

**Considerações**

- O `COLLATE` vai depender do que está definido na tua ligação à base de dados. Para saberes mais podes ver:

  ### [10.1.4 Connection Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)
- Verifica se efetivamente na base de dados está guardado `joão` e não a sua representação em [entidades HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

## Alternativa

Podes resolver mais rapidamente a questão se editares a tabela na base de dados e alterares a `collation` da coluna onde estás a realizar a pesquisa para `UTF-8`, especificamente o `utf8_unicode_ci`, garantindo assim que as letras acentuadas vão ser identificadas na sua versão com ou sem acento.

---

## [Zend 1.12](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building)

Para realizar a consulta utilizando o objeto `Zend_Db_Select` via *fluent interface*:

```
$select = $db->select()
    ->from( "minhaTabela", "*" )
    ->where( "minhaColuna LIKE '%joao%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci" );
```

Comment: E como faço essa consulta usando Zend 1.12? sem alterar o collation do banco.

Comment: @rafaelphp Editei a resposta e adicionei exemplo.

Comment: funcionou certinho aqui colocando o COLLATE na sql, tambem testei mudando o collation da tabela para utf8_general_ci e tambem funcionou sem a necessidade de colocar na sql. Muito Obrigado. Outra dúvida: O que você acha melhor? Trocar o collation das tabelas e/ou banco ou deixar na sql mesmo como no exemplo que vc fez? Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: @rafaelphp Trocar na base de dados, suas tabelas e respetivos campos é sempre melhor. Se deixares essa questão para ser resolvida nas consultas, não só tens mais código para manter no futuro, como é provável vires a perder mais tempo por algum esquecimento de que é preciso especificar o `COLLATE`.