# Problemas em uma consulta no mysql - acentuação

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, se eu pesquisar "Memória" num input,

Eu fiz um código para tirar a acentuação e está indo para query assim:
"Memoria"

Logo, me retorna aqueles que são "Memoria"
O problema é que meu banco de dados também tem palavras escrito "Memória"

Eu preciso, ao consultar "Memória" (no input)

Me trazer tanto com como sem acentuação
O mesmo para quando consultar "Memoria"

O meu problema é que não consigo mudar o where, para pegar tanto um quanto outro.

Os dados sao palavras criadas por um usuario, as vezes ele coloca acentuação, as vezes não, então meu banco de dados fica com os dados alternados.

Comment: Se você deseja que retorne tanto "Memória" quanto "Memoria" uma query simples com o uso de LIKE já resolve (Exemplo: SELECT * FROM palavras WHERE palavra LIKE "memoria";) Esse exemplo deve retornar os dois resultados.

Porém uma informação importante que deve ser destacada é que algumas Collations são case sensitive e outras não.

Tente complementar sua pergunta colocando a estrutura simplificada da tabela que você esta consultando com a query que esta sendo utilizada, bom informar a Collation do Schema (banco de dados) que você criou também.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Consulta no mysql com php não retorna resultado em consultas com acentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57911/consulta-no-mysql-com-php-n%c3%a3o-retorna-resultado-em-consultas-com-acentos)

Comment: Oi, eu já uso o  like %palavra% e não tá funcionando, o problema deve ser no colation mesmo, é este que uso no banco: latin1_swedish_ci

mas não sei resolver, sem alterar o colation no banco, afinal esta tudo funcionando perfeitamente, tem que ser um codigo no where ou algo assim

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira um tanto quanto arriscada, pois pode trazer outros dados que tenham a mesma sequencia de letras é:

```
SELECT * FROM palavras
WHERE palavra LIKE "mem%ria"
```

Mas faça o teste para ver se no seu caso se aplica.

Comment: oi amigo, esse % eu acho que interpreta como uma letra, e tambem palavras neste espaço né? eu precisaria de algo referente a qualquer caracter, tipo um interrogação "?", u caracter coringa, qualquer, vou testar, se for qualquer caracter o %, entao ok, mas se permitir colocar palavras entre, entao nao dara

Comment: ahh, como eu aplico isso numa variavel, como o codigo vai entender onde coloco o % ?

Comment: falta um codigo para ele encontrar a acentuação e substituir por %, pra levar pra query

Comment: é...Sim ele permite qualquer coisa entre esse % desde que o resto seja equivalente antes e depois dele. No caso você tá colocando a query literal dentro do código, ou a query ta puxando uma variável do código pra dentro dela? Por que caso esteja colocando a query literal, ele vai entender tranquilo

Comment: Se puder me passar os códigos eu tento auxiliar