# Converter BD para utf8

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados mysql que é de um projeto muito antigo (~2009).

Os acentos salvos nele estão dessa forma:

- Início = InÃ­cio
- Localização = LocalizaÃ§Ã£o
- Álbum de fotos = ÃÂlbum de fotos

No arquivo SQL, está assim:

> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

E quando vai criar as tabelas está assim:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pagina_extra` (
`ID_PExtra` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ordem_paginas` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `id_menu` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `url_seo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `conteudo` longtext NOT NULL,
  `exibir` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '[S] Sim  [N] Não',
  `interno` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Página interna do sistema. [S]Sim [N]Nao'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77 ;

INSERT INTO `pagina_extra` (`ID_PExtra`, `ordem_paginas`, `id_menu`, `url_seo`, `url`, `nome`, `titulo`, `conteudo`, `exibir`, `interno`) VALUES
(2, 1, 1, 'inicio', 'index.php', 'InÃ­cio', '', '', 'S', 'N'),
(75, 3, 1, 'localizacao', 'pag_localizacao.php', 'LocalizaÃ§Ã£o', '', '', 'N', 'N'),
(76, 12, 1, 'album-de-fotos', 'pag_algum.php', 'ÃÂlbum de fotos', '', '', 'S', 'N');
```

### Pergunta:

O que devo fazer para conseguir importar esse BD e transformar esses caracteres em acentos normais como `í, ç, ã,` etc...

Obrigado.

Comment: Esse problema pode estar até no seu editor de código em relação ao arquivo fonte, considerando que a acentuação não está "escapada" no insert. Tem mais de um problema aí. Precisa verificar os valores reais armazenados em binário nos campos para ver se é erro na visualização ou de armazenamento.

Comment: @Bacco sim, esse foi meu primeiro projeto em ~2009. Estou refazendo todo o código, mas gostaria de aproveitar o mesmo BD. **Pode me ajudar a importar esse BD sem esses caracteres?**. Obrigado

Comment: Está usando phpmyadmin?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, estou.

Comment: Esta ai um gerenciador de banco problemático (phpmyadmin é um gerenciador e não o banco), sempre falhou na hora de importar, justamente com caracteres, eu desisti dele a muito tempo, eu costumo resolver a importação e exportação via linha de comando, neste resposta que fiz https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51317/3635 leia a parte **"Como fazer backups sem ocorrer problemas com a codificação"** e como sugestão para manutenção e gerenciamento poderia experimentar o programa: https://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, mas atualmente não tenho tido problemas com o PHPMyAdmin, acredito que foi um erro no passado, por falta de entendimento e acabei permitindo o salvamento dos dados de forma errada no BD. **Gostaria de saber se é possível reverter esse BD para o formato correto de caracteres.**

Comment: O phpmyadmin na hora de exportar e importar "quebra" os caracteres, ou melhor codifica 2x, você pode pensar não ter um problema com ele, mas com certeza ele (phpmyadmin) tem problemas. Te digo porque tenho um bom tempo de experiencia e larguei ele justamente pq tive muitas dores de cabeça justamente com isto (fora outros problemas que fica complicado enumerar aqui). Gerenciei muitos sites e bancos e volta e meia tinha que ficar abrindo o notepad++ pra mudar o codec dos .sql pra corrigir, por culpa do phpmyadmin

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi. Vou baixar o Heidisql, com ele consigo importar e converter esses caracteres loucos em acentos corretos?

Comment: Experimente abrir o .sql no notepad++ e salvar como cópia com windows-1252, então feche e abra novamente a copia .sql e verifique se ficaram "corretos".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vou baixar ele e já te falo. Obrigado até o momento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento consegui. Fui separando as tabelas que tem o problema de caracters e no notepad++ fui alternando em ASCI e UTF-8 e deu certo. Coloca sua resposta ai para marcar como resolvido.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, pode explicar mais sobre esse arquivo cópia com *windows-1252*, não entendi esse win-1252...

Comment: @AndréFilipe crie uma copia do teu .sql, abra no notepad++, vá no menu do topo aonde esta escrito "Codificação", selecione "Converter para ANSI", salve o doc e abra novamente

Comment: Ahhh sim, conhecia essa técnica. Só não estava claro pra mim esse termo windows-1252. Tem alguma relação esse padrão ANSI com o *windows-1252*?

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira evitar ter que sempre inserir no código, você pode mudar direto no console do gerenciador do banco de dados:

```
ALTER DATABASE nome_banco DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score -1):

Se estiver usando PDO, só adicionar o  `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`  assim na conexão que ele mostrar normal. Conforme o exemplo abaixo.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$banco; charset=utf8", $usuario, $senha,
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

}
```

Comment: Bom dia. Como fazer em mysqli? não uso pdo :(