# Problema de acentuação PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, acentuação

Estou com um problema muito estranho do meu código PHP.

Todos os meus charset estão corretos

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Ja utilizo o codigo abaixo para corrigir problemas de acentuação

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Quando eu envio o formulário para o MySQL ele grava no banco com acento corretamente (banco de dados em latin1_swedish_ci).

Tudo aparece perfeitamente na tela.

O problema aparece quando eu faço um str_replace. Quando eu pego a variável da URL pelo método $_GET (que está com acento correto) e coloco na função str_replace, a função não reconhece a letra com acento e não faz a troca.
Agora, se eu escrevo no meu código a mesma palavra ( `<?php $str = "joão" ?>` por exemplo ), dai a função reconhece o acento.

O problema também acontece quando o código compara uma palavra com o que está no banco de dados. Se ele comparar uma letra com acento que esta no código com uma palavra que tem acento no banco, ele não reconhece (então não retorna nenhum resultado).

Estou utilizando o str_replace para fazer buscas com REGEXP, então meu código pega uma palavra com acento, troca por uma palavra igual sem acento (aqui eu ja tenho o erro) e depois cria uma string com REGEXP para fazer a busca.

Por favor, ajudem que já não sei mais onde procurar!

Comment: Conselho de amigo: confere os arquivos. Provavelmente seus arquivos estão codificados como iso8859-1, um editor de texto bom como Sublime Text, Atom etc te permite converter. Sobre o banco de dados, se no banco vc usar o iso8859-1 é só lembrar de colocar o mesmo ISO no `mysql_query`. Não é "gambiarra" como o colega disse, é um sistema de conversão automática do PHP, que funciona muito bem caso você saiba o que está fazendo. É só especificar no PHP os mesmos charsets pro banco, tabela, campos etc. Que você usou no banco, e eles convertem tudo perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Banco de dados `latin1_swedish_ci` não deve ser usado com `utf8`, se não você vai ficar na gambiarra para resolver o problema.

Se usa banco `latin1`, então use na página `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

Este problema ocorre por que os caracteres acentuados do utf8 são totalmente diferentes do latin1, então para o banco são duas coisas diferentes.

Se vai usar páginas em `utf-8`, então use o banco em `utf-8`, recomendo ler isto:

- [Qual "collate" UTF-8 é o mais apropriada para Web (multi-linguagem)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43281/3635)
- [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

Comment: Eu mudei meu banco para utf8, e mesmo assim não adiantou. Como foi comentado acima, também achei estranho mas a url esta com acento! Pode ser algum problema com o php.ini? Ja tentei mudar algumas configurações e não deu certo.

Comment: @GabrielOliveira Você usou `ALTER TABLE sua_tabela CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE charset_escolhido_por_você;`? Qual charset você usou?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma alternativa é que se estivermos utilizando **PDO**, o quarto parâmetro no momento de instanciar a classe PDO é super importante para situações de caracteres especiais.

```
//Fazemos a conexão com nosso banco de dados

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=nome_do_banco;host=localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; //usuário do banco
$dbpass = ""; //senha do banco
try
{
    //Instanciamos a classe PDO passando como parâmetro os dados de conexão pegos acima
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'')); 
    //Esse quarto parâmetro é para corrigir problemas de acentuação

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{   
   //Se der erro na conexão, nós estourando esse Catch e é exibida essa mensagem junto com a mensagem do erro
   echo "A conexão falhou: ".$e->getMessage();
   exit;
}
```

**Esse é o parâmetro que me refiro:**

```
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'')
```

- Além, é claro, de termos que deixar os COLLATE e CHARSET do banco e das tabelas do banco de dados configurados da maneira correta.

Answer (score -3):

Corrigi o problema de acentuação da seguinte forma:

```
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'')
```