# acentuações entre php e mysql como utilizar?

Tags: php, mysql

qual a forma correta de criar o banco de dados e tabelas no mysql 5.6 para que atenda aos padrões brasileiros de carácteres?

a versão do meu php é 5.6 e uso a seguinte informação no header dos arquivos php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

e no html está assim

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

mas todas as vezes que busco dados no banco preciso utilizar as funções

```
utf8_decode();
utf8_encode();
```

o banco de dados foi criado da seguinte forma Tipo:InnoDB, Colação: utf8_general_ci, a forma como foi criado está correta? ou está correto utilizar as funções utf8 do php para corrigir o problema de acentuação?

Comment: Pode ser a codificação do seu arquivo, abra ele com Notepad++ para verificar se ele está como utf-8 (sem bom).

Comment: sim estou utilizando o notepad++ sem dom e utf-8

Comment: Tente setar o charset na conexão também. Aqui tem algumas dicas também, http://rmonte.com/acentuacao-no-php-e-mysql-com-utf-8/

Comment: @Augusto obrigado pela dica não sabia que dava para setar o charset pela conexão, vou fazer os testes.

Comment: Blz, aqui também uma explicação bem detalhada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rapaz, também usava tudo como utf-8 e ainda sim tinha problemas com acentuação. O jeito que encontrei para lidar com isso é rodar uma query ***SET NAMES 'utf8'*** logo depois de conectar no banco. Deixo ela direto no arquivo de conexão. Segue abaixo:

```
//MySQLi DESENVOLVIMENTO
$db_host="localhost";
$db_port="5432";
$db_name="testedb";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";

$dbcon = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_password );
mysqli_select_db($dbcon,$db_name);
mysqli_query($dbcon,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Antes de responder pesquise se já não existe uma pergunta e/ou resposta que resolvem o problema e então se encontrar prefira marcar como duplicata ao invés de responder http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=php%20mysql%20acentuação

Comment: Ok. Farei isso.

Comment: vi vários comentários para criar o banco de dados, e qual é a melhor? utf8mb4? utf8_unicode_ci? ou utf8_general_ci? vou usar caracteres de acentução do dicionário pt-BT

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso veja a resposta do Gmsantos http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43285/3635

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso eu costumo usar o utf8_general_ci pra tudo e nunca tenho problemas.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi Eu também uso utf8_general_ci, pois dificilmente faço comparações "complexas", mas se precisar de coisas que tem haver com som talvez seja melhor verificar as necessidade primeiro, afinal existem motivações boas para cada um destes. Em geral para páginas simples atende bem, em casos de necessitar de emojis talvez seja necessário o utf8mb4 já citado. Só vendo caso a caso dos requisitos. Até mais pessoal

Comment: Uhum.  Concordo Guilherme.  Curti o link q vc passou.