# Erro de acentuação no mysql

Tags: mysql, asp, codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação

Estou com problema de acentuação no banco de dados do meu site.

Por exemplo, no banco de dados o texto está "**elétrico**", mas é postado no site como "**elÃ©trico**"

Tentei algumas coisas, porém agora no lugar dos "**acentos**" fica com "**?**" (interrogação)

Já tentei vários encodings.

Comment: Seu site está sendo desenvolvido em que linguagem?

Comment: Gabriel no momento está em ASP e em breve até dezembro 2018 vou migrar para  PHP

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Todas as tabelas estão com DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 mas sem COLLATE definido, conforme disponibilizado no dump (exemplo abaixo).

```
CREATE TABLE `adsense` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `codigo` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `canal` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `local` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `publicado` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Faça um backup da base de dados e remova tudo da BD atual, depois execute o seguinte comando:

```
ALTER DATABASE `ConteudoAnimal` CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Após isso faça o processo novamente de criação das tabelas e importação dos dados. Vários dados que estão no export atual já estão "estragados" pois foram inseridos com o encoding errado, portanto não servirão para fazer insert nas tabelas.

Veja por exemplo que a tabela de Noticias está com o collate correto no campo varchar e este possui os dados sem problema de encoding. Deverá ser feita uma verificação item a item.

Comment: Agradeço a atenção de todos 
Já fiz as correções de todos 
Agora só falta corrigir os dados legados incluidos erradamente 
Mas os novos já estão todos certos !
Obrigado MESMO

Answer (score 6):

Usar isto:

```
 ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Só vai alterar a sua base de dados para UTF8, e isso não define nada e nem resolve nada, existem multiplos tipos de charset e provavelmente você tem que ver qual é o ideal para ti, por exemplo os mais usados são UTF-8 e Latin1 e dentro destes 2 existem variações ainda no mysql, veja mais detalhes em:

- [Qual "collate" UTF-8 é o mais apropriada para Web (multi-linguagem)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43281/3635)

Então primeiro você deve ter certeza de qual charset é o que deseja, se for latin1 ou utf8, por exemplo se você deseja usar latin1 alterar as tabelas ou o banco com `ALTER` só vai mudar a codificação para algo que talvez já esteja conforme a codificação que deseja.

---

### O problema dos caracteres

O problemas com caracteres como `Ã©` ou `�` ocorre por má configuração do banco até os seus scripts asp (ou php), então **não é um erro** do banco, mas sim um erro de compreensão de como trabalhar com isto.

Se vai usar UTF8 no banco você deve:

- Salvar **TODOS** os scripts como **UTF-8 sem BOM**
- Setar o charset durante a conexão com o banco
- Definir o header HTTP na resposta da requisição como por exemplo Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8

Se vai usar Latin1 no banco você deve:

- Salvar **TODOS** os scripts como **ANSI** (ou ISO-8859-1 ou window-1252)
- Setar o charset durante a conexão com o banco
- Definir o header HTTP na resposta da requisição como por exemplo `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` (ou `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252`)

---

> Atenção, para que funcione você deve seguir todos os passos:
>
> - Escolher a codificação que vai lhe atender melhor, latin1 ou utf8
> - Setar a conexão corretamente
> - Setar os charset http com o mesmo charset desejado
> - Salvar todos documentos/script sem exceção que vão usar os dados do banco com a mesma codificação

### Configurando UTF-8

Você deve salvar todos scripts ASP (até os que você usará com `<!--#include file="..."-->`) em utf-8 sem "BOM", você pode utilizar softwares como [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) ou [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) para converter os arquivos:

- Usando notepad++:

  [image: utf8 sem bom notepad++]
- Usando Sublime Text:

  [image: utf8 sublime sublimetext]

Depois deve definir na conexão para usar UTF8 usando o comando `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`:

> Se já estiver configurado no arquivo `my.ini` isto pode ser dispensável, mas eu manteria para evitar problemas se alguém editar o `my.ini`

```vb
Dim cnnSimple  ' ADO connection
Dim rstSimple  ' ADO recordset
Set cnnSimple = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")     

cnnSimple.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=[mySQL server];
DATABASE=[DBName];UID=[DBUser];PASSWORD=[DB Password];"

Set rstSimple = cnnSimple.Execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8") 'Define o charset
```

---

### Configurando latin1

Primeiro deve salvar "todos scripts .asp" como iso-8859-1 (ou ANSI):

- Para salvar usando notepad++:

  [image: salvando documento em ANSI com notepad++]
- Para salvar usando SublimeText:

  [image: salvando documento em iso-8859-1 ou windows 1252]

Depois deve definir na conexão para usar UTF8 usando o comando `SET CHARACTER SET latin1`:

> Se já estiver configurado no arquivo `my.ini` isto pode ser dispensável, mas eu manteria para evitar problemas se alguém editar o `my.ini`

```vb
Dim cnnSimple  ' ADO connection
Dim rstSimple  ' ADO recordset
Set cnnSimple = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")     

cnnSimple.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};SERVER=[mySQL server];
DATABASE=[DBName];UID=[DBUser];PASSWORD=[DB Password];"

Set rstSimple = cnnSimple.Execute("SET CHARACTER SET latin1") 'Define o charset
```

---

### Setando o charset HTTP

Você pode fazer de duas maneiras isto, via HTML ou via `response`, segue:

- Usando UTF-8 no HTML

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  ```
- Usando UTF-8 no `response` que deve ir antes de qualquer conteudo HTML:

  ```vb
  <%@Language=VBScript CodePage = 65001%>
  <%
  Response.charset ="utf-8"
  Response.CodePage = 65001
  %>
  <html>
  ...
  ```
- Usando latin1 (iso-8859-1 ou windows-1252) no HTML

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  ```
- Usando UTF-8 no `response` que deve ir antes de qualquer conteudo HTML:

  ```vb
  <%@Language=VBScript CodePage = 65001%>
  <%
  Response.charset ="iso-8859-1" 'pode usar windows-1252 também
  Response.CodePage = 28591
  %>
  <html>
  ...
  ```

---

### Conclusão

Se seguiu todos passos corretamente provavelmente não haverá mais falhas, nem na leitura do banco nem na gravação dos dados, tudo que foi dito nesta resposta é o mesmo que eu já expliquei em:

- [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193/3635) (veja a resposta)

Comment: Agradeço a atenção de todos Já fiz as correções de todos Agora só falta corrigir os dados legados incluidos erradamente Mas os novos já estão todos certos ! Obrigado MESMO

Sobre o 
<%@Language=VBScript CodePage = 65001%>
<%
Response.charset ="iso-8859-1" 'pode usar windows-1252 também
Response.CodePage = 28591
%>
Não foi aceito pelo servidor que hospedo o site  mas tá valendo porque agora tá tudo praticamente certo !!!

Comment: @user2832991 obrigado pelo feedback, poderia marcar a resposta como correta? Se não souber como é feito leia isto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o seguinte comando nas tabelas que estão dando problema com acentuação.

```
 ALTER TABLE `sua_tabela` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Isto ocorre por que no Charset definido para seu MySQL não possui este tipo de acentuação. Com o comando acima você irá utilizar o charset latino, que possui estes caracteres.

Ou você também pode alterar de todo database com o seguinte comando

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Agradeço a atenção de todos Já fiz as correções de todos Agora só falta corrigir os dados legados incluidos erradamente Mas os novos já estão todos certos ! Obrigado MESMO